# Summation of rows on a combination of two columns

Tags: sql

I'm trying to do a summation of rows but to be picked based on bit tricky match of columns, to demonstrate; I have a table1 as below:

### Table1

```
Year.....V1....V2....V3....V4....ORIG....DEST
2015.....12....12....12....12....AAAA....BBBB
2015.....12....13....14....15....BBBB....AAAA
```

And the list goes down for different pairs of ORIG and DEST and for three years (2015, 2016, and 2017).
Then I have my main table where it is the same structure however it only has the summation of the two legs of data on ORIG and DEST basis (i.e. summation of all variables V1-V4 for AAAA to BBBB AND BBBB to AAAA) but for years before 2015, (1996-2014), as below:

### Table2

```
Year.....V1....V2....V3....V4....ORIG....DEST
1996.....20....20....20....20....AAAA....BBBB
1997.....12....13....14....15....AAAA....BBBB
```

And the list goes down for up to 2014 and with different pairs of ORIG and DEST.
What I'm trying to do is to sum the rows in Table1 where ORIG = DEST AND DEST = ORIG, however the tricky part is that the summed rows in Table2 had been allocated a random name combination for the ORIG and DEST(i.e. to sum rows of ORIG and DEST AAAA and BBBB, the possible values to be allocated to the new ORIG and DEST columns in Table 2 is either AAAA to BBBB or BBBB to AAAA and it was randomly picked) which makes it problematic to match my summations of Table1 to Table2 when I want to union.
I had thought of doing the summation and then duplicate the row and on each one give the possibilities of ORIG and DEST and the inner join will pick the similar ones.
So my questions are, if this is likely to work? what are possibly the ways to code it?
If there is any other way that you might suggest?

Thank you.

Comment: Need more records on sample data and expected output

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.